# Не удается создать Render Target на основе заднего буфера от DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, direct2d

Не понимаю что я мог сделать не так, но по каким-то причинам, я не могу создать объект `ID2D1RenderTareget`, с использовfнием заднего буфера `IDXGISwapChain`, всегда происходит провал с ошибкой, `E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.`, при этом сам `Direct2D` не сообщает ни о каких ошибках, как к примеру если не правильно указать формат поверхности, то он в вывод отладчика печатает о том что формат поверхности не поддерживается.

Как я пытаюсь получить `ID2D1RenderTarget`:

```
bool engine::init_renderer(const uint32_t width, const uint32_t height)
{
    DWORD d3d_device_flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)
    d3d_device_flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL feature_levels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
    };

    constexpr UINT features_count = sizeof feature_levels / sizeof*feature_levels;

    const DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swap_chain_description =
    {

        {
            width,
            height,

            {
                60u, // by default
                1u // by default
            },

            DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
            DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED,
            DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED
        },

        {
            1u,
            0u
        },

        DXGI_USAGE_BACK_BUFFER,
        2u,
        m_render_window_.get_handle(),
        TRUE,
        DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD,
        0
    };

    HRESULT result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain
    (
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        d3d_device_flags,
        feature_levels,
        features_count,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &swap_chain_description,
        &p_dxgi_swap_chain_,
        &p_d3d_device_,
        &m_current_feature_level_,
        &p_d3d_immediate_context_
    );

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    result = p_d3d_device_.As(&p_dxgi_device_);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    com<IDXGIDevice1> dxgi_device;

    result = p_dxgi_device_.As(&dxgi_device);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    const D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS factory_options
    {
        D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION
    };

    result = D2D1CreateFactory<ID2D1Factory3>(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, factory_options, &p_d2d_factory_);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    com<IDXGISwapChain2> swap_chain;

    result = p_dxgi_swap_chain_.As(&swap_chain);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    com<ID3D11Texture2D> d3d_back_buffer;

    result = swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3d_back_buffer));

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    result = d3d_back_buffer.As(&p_dxgi_back_buffer_);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    float dpi_x = 96.f, dpi_y = 96.f;

    p_d2d_factory_->GetDesktopDpi(&dpi_x, &dpi_y);

    const D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES render_target_properties
    {
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        {
            DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN,
            D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED
        },
        dpi_x,
        dpi_y,
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE,
        D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT
    };

    result = p_d2d_factory_->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(p_dxgi_back_buffer_.Get(), &render_target_properties,
                                                           &p_d2d_render_target_);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        const std::wstring error = win_api_helper::instance().hresult_to_string(result);
        OutputDebugString(error.c_str());
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    ...

    return true;
}
```

Что может мешать созданию `ID2D1RenderTarget`, если я вроде бы все учел о том о чем было написано в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-direct3d-interoperation-overview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне представляется, что при создании буферов необходимо указывать `DXGI_USAGE_BACK_BUFFER bitor DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT`, а не только `DXGI_USAGE_BACK_BUFFER`, иначе их нельзя будет использовать в качестве цели рисования.